# After submitting how can I pass JS variables to following PHP in the same PHP file?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

After a user fills his address in a text field and hits the submit button the address is sent to google maps by javascript which then receives back the coordinates of the address.
I then want to pass the coordinates back to a following PHP code so I can save them to the DB.
So if this is the code under a single PHP file how can this be done?

P.S. Just to be clearer, all of this is done under one PHP function that handles the submitting.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
...
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.latitude;
var lng = results[0].geometry.location.longitude;
...
}
</script>
<?php
$latitude = ??? ;
$longitude = ??? ;
?>
```

Comment: will nor work that way, bare in mind, PHP is executed BEFORE the webpage is displayed in the Browser, JS is executed AFTER The Browser finished rendering in the browser [ of course thats simplifying it ]

Comment: Hannes + 1. You can't do this way but there are some work around.

Comment: @Hannes - The PHP code I'm talking about is handling the already submitted form, not creating it. Can't it now run a javascript that sends and gets info from google maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get the lat/long in the page when submit is clicked - before the form is submitted to you your handling PHP script - just store the results in hidden inputs;

`<input id="lat" type="hidden" name="lat" value=""/>`

using js to update their values after you receive them from the API call;

```
$("lat").value = results[0].geometry.location.latitude;
```

Then allow the form to submit as normal and fetch "`lat`" from the query string/post data.

Comment: Alex, thanks, but I'm not sure we're in sync.
I'm getting the lat/lng after the form is submitted. The PHP that handles the submitting is firing the JS that "talks" with Google's API. I want to get the the API's reply and store it in the DB.

Comment: Oh, so your not getting the values in the submit event of the form in client side js?

Comment: I'm getting them (at least, I think I do. Haven't verified it yet), I just don't know how to pass them back from the JS to the PHP code so I can store them in the DB.

Comment: If you fetch them client side, you can just append them to the form? - you can do this in the onsubmit event

Comment: I'm actually using a WordPress PHP plugin. It gets the submitted fields by PHP. Now, I'm adding to it a Javascript to send the address to Google's API. Can I still pass the results back to PHP after doing so?

Comment: @Alex - on second thought I'll try that. I'll change the plugin so that the "talk" with the API will run right after the submit, before PHP handles the outcome and will put the results hidden in the form for the PHP to pickup. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, PHP executes before the client receives the file (after which the user's browser executes the JavaScript)

What you want can easily be achieved by using AJAX. Have the JavaScript call an external php file which would simply get the variables it receives and inserts it into the database. For example in your ajax request, have the url be the address to your external php file with the variables appended to the uri query:

```
"storedata.php?latitude="+lat+"&longitude="+lng
```

Then in `storedata.php`:

```
$latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
$longitude = $_GET['longitude'];

// process them here and insert into your database .etc
```

Comment: Probably my fault, my question wasn't clear enough. The PHP code I'm focusing on is the one that handles the submitted form. It gets the address from the address field, and then runs javascript to send the address to Google's API. Now I want to pass the API's reply back to the PHP code for DB storing.

Comment: So you have your form, user enters data, php passes the entered data to javascript which loads the google map data into some javascript variables, now you want to save those returned variables to your database?

Why not just use AJAX to pass the returned variables to a PHP script which saves them to your database?

Comment: That's a possibility. I couldn't find a simple example for doing it.